# $A\in \mathcal{L}(H)$ and $\langle x,Ay\rangle =\langle Ax,y \rangle,\forall x,y\in H$. Prove $Q(A)(H)=H$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $A\in \mathcal{L}(H)$, where $\mathcal{L}(H)$ is the space of bounded linear operator, $H$ is real Hilbert space and $\langle x,Ay\rangle =\langle Ax,y \rangle,\forall x,y\in H$, $\operatorname{ker}A=\{0\}$. Put $Q(t)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^na_kt^k$, $a_k\in \mathbb{R}$ where $Q(t)=0$ has no solutions on $\mathbb{R}$. Prove $Q(A)(H)=H$.

I tried use Lax Milgram theorem but no problem yet

Comment: Is this a real or complex Hilbert space?

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Real Hilbert space

Comment: How is $Q(A)$ defined? What do you know about injective operators? What do you know about self-adjoint operators? Have you tried using the assumption that $Q(t)$ has no solutions on $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @supinf $Q(A)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^na_kA^k$. Yes, i  tried using the assumption that $Q(t)$ has no solutions on $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial $Q(t)$ is real, with no real roots. Therefore, it may be written as a non-zero constant times products of terms $(t-t_k)^2+v_k^2$ where $t_k,v_k$ are real. Because $A$ is symmetric, then $(A-t_kI)^2+v_k^2I$ is surjective. It follows that $Q(A)$ is surjective.

Comment: I don't understand why "Because $A$ is symmetric, then $(A-t_kI)^2+v_k^2I$ is surjective" . Can you explain more carefully ?

Comment: @Peter : You're working with a real space. So $\langle ((A-t_kI)^2+v_k^2 I)x,x\rangle=\|(A-t_kI)x\|^2+v_k^2\|x\|^2$, which means that $\mathcal{N}((A-t_kI)^2+v_k^2I)=\{0\}$ So the range is dense. The range is full because the operator is also bounded below.

Comment: Can you explain more "The range is full because the operator is also bounded below" ? Thanks

Comment: @Peter : $B=(A-t_kI)^2+v_k^2I$. $\langle Bx,x\rangle \ge v_k^2\|x\|^2$ forces $\|Bx\|\ge |v_k|\|x\|$. So the inverse of $B$ has a unique continuous extension to the closure of the range of $B$, which is dense.